# Issues when pip install libraries in my host machine

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to use pip (9.0.1) in my macosx (python 2.7.10) but whenever I install something I keep getting these errors:

```
Collecting flask
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10b8fa310>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',)': /simple/flask/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10b8fa110>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',)': /simple/flask/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10b8fa550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',)': /simple/flask/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10b8fa850>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',)': /simple/flask/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10b8facd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',)': /simple/flask/
```

Some guy mentioned that might be related to the firewall so I connected to the network via my phone and then I execute pip in this case things seem to get installed but I still get all this "retrying" before it downloads every package like:

```
Collecting flask
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10b8fa310>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',)': /simple/flask/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10b8fa110>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',)': /simple/flask/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10b8fa550>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',)': /simple/flask/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10b8fa850>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',)': /simple/flask/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x10b8facd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',)': /simple/flask/ 
Downloading Flask-0.12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (83kB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 1.8MB/s 
Collecting itsdangerous>=0.21 (from flask)
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by '
```

Any idea why I get these messages?

Comment: which command did you tried ?

Comment: @Dadep pip install flask

Comment: did you try `easy_install flask` ?

Comment: Nope. But pip used to work. I still don't understand what parameters I should pass in the --proxy flag of pip. I am installing this in my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

pip has `proxy` option. Please use it.

```
pip install flask --proxy=<proxy address>
```

From `pip --help`

> --proxy  Specify a proxy in the form [user:passwd@]proxy.server:port.

Read about proxy address [here](https://www.whatismyip.com/what-is-a-proxy/).

Refer [this](https://kb.k12usa.com/knowledgebase/proxy-settings-on-a-mac-os-x) to setup proxy on mac os.

Comment: I am not sure what parameters to pass by in proxy address.

Comment: But I am not sure what this means. Should I specify a proxy in my mac? How do I do that? I tried to specify one from Network preferences. Would that be the way?

Comment: I have no idea what proxy parameters to pass there. This is not clear at all to me.

Comment: @user1919 I've edited the answer with details about proxy